# How access JS function using Import Maps in Ruby On Rails 7?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

I'm newbie to JS modules and Import Map, now I'm using Ruby on Rails 7 and I couldn't find a way to get this working:

**Js Module (proposals.js):**

```
function openProposalMirror() ...
```

**application.js**

```
import * as Proposal from "./proposals.js"
```

**On the view:**

```
onclick="Proposal.openProposalMirror()"
```

> error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Proposal is not defined

**How could I accesse openProposalMirror() function on the view?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to go is to assign the `Proposal` to the object `window.Proposal`.

you could set directly inside the `application.js` as below:

```js
// proposals.js
function openProposalMirror() {}
export { openProposalMirror }

// application.js
import * as Proposal from "./proposals.js"
window.Proposal = Proposal

// view
onclick="Proposal.openProposalMirror()"
```

you could also re-export `Proposal` from `application.js` then import and assign it to the object `window.Proposal` in a `<script>` tag (in view) as below:

```js
// application.js
import * as Proposal from "./proposals.js"
export { Proposal };

// view
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>

<script type="module">
  import { Proposal } from "application"
  window.Proposal = Proposal;
</script>
```

Comment: It took me an hour to find this Q&A, and it _felt_ like it was my problem. The question I have is now is: why is this necessary? (Specifically, I'm trying to use AgGrid.)

Comment: @DavidKrider as i said in my answer, this is just a `one way to go`, i just curious and try to solve this question, i'd not ever used this way so far. Trying other ways and use the one you though that better.

Answer (score 1):

In my example, I'm trying to use Ag-Grid. After pinning the source:

```
bin/importmap pin ag-grid-community
```

All I had to do was do the import in my .html.erb file:

```
<script type="module">

  import { Grid } from "ag-grid-community"

  var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
      { headerName: 'Make', field: 'make' },
      { headerName: 'Model', field: 'model' },
      { headerName: 'Price', field: 'price' }
    ],
    rowData: [
      { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
      { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
      { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxster', price: 72000 }
    ]
  }
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid')
    new Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions)
  })

</script>
```

So, not the usual `<%= javascript do %>`, but rather `<script type="module">`. Once included in the importmap, nothing needs to be added to application.js.