# Rails 7 Highcharts ganttChart is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

Highcharts is working when not calling Gantt chart in other views. I've played around trying to get this Gantt chart to work. Looks like there is a conflict with import map only calling highcharts and highcharts.ganttChart is not found. I've tried added the src url through a script tag directly in the html view but still getting this error.

````
Error msg <
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Highcharts.ganttChart is not a function
>

Javascript controller
```
import {Controller} from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {

    connect() {
        
        let today = new Date(),
            day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

        today.setUTCHours(0);
        today.setUTCMinutes(0);
        today.setUTCSeconds(0);
        today.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
        today = today.getTime();

        let dateFormat = Highcharts.dateFormat;
        let series
        let chart; // global
       
        async function requestData() {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/charts/index');
            if (response.ok) {
                const data = await response.json();
                series = data.map(function (job, i) {
                    let data = job.deals.map(function (phase) {
                        return {
                            id: 'deal-' + i,
                            project: phase.project,
                            client: phase.client,
                            phase: phase.phase,
                            start: new Date(phase.from).getTime(),
                            end: new Date(phase.to).getTime(),
                            y: i
                        };
                    });
                    return {
                        name: job.name,
                        data: data,
                        current: job.deals[job.current]
                    };
                });
                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
                console.log(series);

                chart = Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {

                    series: series,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Crew Schedule'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '<span>Client {point.client}</span><br/>' +
                            '<span>Project: {point.project}</span><br/>' +
                            '<span>Phase: {point.phase}</span><br/>' +
                            '<span>From: {point.start:%e. %b}</span><br/><span>To: {point.end:%e. %b}</span>'
                    },
                    lang: {
                        accessibility: {
                            axis: {
                                xAxisDescriptionPlural: 'The chart has a two-part X axis showing time in both week numbers and days.',
                                yAxisDescriptionSingular: 'The chart has a tabular Y axis showing a data table row for each point.'
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    scrollbar: {
                        enabled: true
                    },

                    rangeSelector: {
                        enabled: true,
                        selected: 0
                    },
                    accessibility: {
                        keyboardNavigation: {
                            seriesNavigation: {
                                mode: 'serialize'
                            }
                        },
                        point: {
                            valueDescriptionFormat: 'Assigned to {point.project} from   {point.x:%A, %B %e} to {point.x2:%A, %B %e}.'
                        },
                        series: {
                            descriptionFormatter: function (series) {
                                return series.name + ', job ' + (series.index + 1) + ' of ' + series.chart.series.length + '.';
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        currentDateIndicator: true
                    },


                    navigator: {
                        enabled: true,
                        liveRedraw: true,
                        series: {
                            type: 'gantt',
                            pointPlacement: 0.5,
                            pointPadding: 0.25,
                            accessibility: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            max: 3,
                            reversed: true,
                            categories: []
                        }
                    },


                    yAxis: {
                        type: 'category',
                        grid: {
                            columns: [{
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Crew'
                                },
                                categories: series.map(function (s) {
                                    return s.name;
                                })
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            return chart;
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
            requestData();
        });
    }
}
````

Comment: How have you included Highcharts (the base library)? I can't even get that far.

Comment: Yeah, you need to pin Highcharts in the importmap.rb
```
pin "highcharts", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:highcharts@10.1.0/highcharts.js"
```

Comment: I actually found a workaround still have some issues with chart loading on the window.load I need to refresh the page then the chart with populate.

I am using this for now
<script>
    let Highgantt = Highcharts;
    Highcharts = null;

</script>

Comment: Since posting that question, I've worked this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70686825/how-access-js-function-using-import-maps-in-ruby-on-rails-7/72722736#72722736. You should be able to pin "highcharts-gantt", and then, in your page, do `import { Highcharts } from "highcharts"` and `import { Gantt } from "highcharts-gantt"`, then use each object, respectively.

Comment: @DavidKrider I guess this still is not working for me at least with using the Javascript Controller. I have it working with my above solution still but the page needs to be refreshed once before the Gantt will load